# How to merge two datatables with PrimaryKeys?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two data tables and want merge columns and create as third table.

```
//Given
dt1 {A(PK),B,C,D}
dt2 {a(PK),b,c,d}
//Want
dtResult {A,B,C,D,a,b,c,d}
```

Do not want to lose `ExtendedProperties` so not Selecting `DataColumn.ColumnName` and adding as columns.

**Code:**

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.TableName = "dt1";
dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns.Add("A") };
dt1.Columns.Add("B");
dt1.Columns.Add("C");
dt1.Columns.Add("D");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.TableName = "dt2";
dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns.Add("a") };
dt2.Columns.Add("b");
dt2.Columns.Add("c");
dt2.Columns.Add("d");

var dtResult = dt1.Clone();
dtResult.TableName = "dtResult";
```

Working fine till here

Now want to merge...

**Multiple merge tries type 1**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone()); 
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey); 
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `merged` into dtResult but throws `NullReferenceException`.
StackTrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
   at Demo.Program.Test5() in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 54
   at Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\App\Program.cs:line 36
```

**Multiple merge tries type 2**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `NOT merged` into dtResult and `System.Data.DataException`
StackTrace:

```
System.Data.DataException
  HResult=0x80131920
  Message=Target table  missing definition for column a.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
   at Demo.Program.Test5() in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 54
   at Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 36
```

**Multiple merge tries type 3**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `NOT merged` into dtResult and `NO exception`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: dtResult should have all columns (A,B,C,D,a,b,c,d). Key columns are optional to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the NullReferenceException occurs because the two tables have primary keys. We need to do something to avoid that conflict.

There you go:

```
var dtResult = dt1.Clone();
dtResult.TableName = "dtResult";

var dt2Cloned = dt2.Clone();
dt2Cloned.PrimaryKey = null;
dtResult.Merge(dt2Cloned);

var primaryKeys = dtResult.PrimaryKey.ToList();
foreach (var col in dt2.PrimaryKey)
{
    primaryKeys.Add(dtResult.Columns[col.ColumnName]);
}
dtResult.PrimaryKey = primaryKeys.ToArray();
```

This can probably be optimized a little but it gets you the result you need so it's a good start.

Comment: Thankyou very much @Ahmed Abdelhameed. Making ```PrimaryKey=null``` did not tricked into my mind, instead of this I was trying to remove that column. As I do not care about re-applying keys into new table so ```PrimaryKey=null``` is enough. Thanks again!

Comment: Well I read the reason at some blog had also mentioned in the question but somehow I removed the line after editing the question. But didn't know how to resolve it. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer by @Ahmed Abdelhameed.

If you are facing problem like `Unique column cannot have same value` or `null is not allowed` add below code.

```
var dt2Cloned = dt2.Clone();
var pks = dt2Cloned.PrimaryKey.ToList();
dt2Cloned.PrimaryKey = null;
pks.ForEach(pk => { pk.Unique = false; pk.AllowDBNull = true; });
```

You can also do same for `PKs` of `dt1` , if required.